# Bootstrap 100%-height page with a responsive news section

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I'm creating a 100%-width/100%-height (no scrollbars) website with Bootstrap and I want to make a news section (just like an iframe). Width: OK. The problem is that I can't make the height responsive. I want the news section's height to change, so I dont get "blank spaces" in bigger screens or scrollbars in smaller ones. (I'd like a 80%-height iframe).

Any hints? This is how I wanted to look like:

[image]

Comment: I have a solution with jquery. Is it acceptable?

Comment: jQuery is not needed: Hint: `position: absolute`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can play with VH

15vh = 15/100 of the viewport’s current height or 15% of the height

Use it like this

```
.content{
  min-height: 100vh; // define your VH
}
```

Please read this article
http://www.tipue.com/blog/css3-vw-vh/